# difference between SELECT queries embedded in for loop vs WHERE id IN syntax

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Do one of these approaches perform better? Is there a better approach? Why? Does it matter that I'm doing this in python or not? (You can correctly assume there is an index on the `id` column of `my_table`).

1. Running `SELECT` statements, embedded in for loop:

   ```py
   for an_id in a_long_list_of_ids:
      cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id=%s", (an_id,))
      do_something(cursor.fetchall())
   ```
2. Running a single `SELECT` statement using `WHERE id IN` syntax:

   ```py
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN (%s)", 
       (','.join(a_long_list_of_ids),)
   )
   do_something(cursor.fetchall())
   ```

Comment: The second will likely run better as a result of fewer queries to the db

Comment: Agree with @megawac. It's typically better to allow the db do these types of calculations due to the overhead associated with setting up a connection and locating the data on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of

```
for an_id in a_long_list_of_ids:
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id=%s", (an_id,))
   do_something(cursor.fetchall())
```

you are doing `len(a_long_list_of_ids)` queries to the db.

In case of

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN (%s)", 
    (','.join(a_long_list_of_ids),)
)
do_something(cursor.fetchall())
```

you are doing only one query.

It's clear that the second way is more performant.

If you want more performance select only columns you will be using - this is faster.

If you are going to make additional filtering on Python side, consider putting filtering logic in the query - this will also make the processing faster.

Comment: So is it just the overhead of setting up a query and communicating with a server that causes option #2 to be faster? If the query is slow, I'd expect this difference to be negligable, but from a quick test, I've seen a 2x improvement of option #2 over option #1.

Comment: Each query means connecting to the server, passing it the query, waiting for the server to execute the query, serializing the result and passing it over the connection back to the client. It doesn't matter how complex is the query. It's clear that performing a query once is faster than performing (almost the same query - with just one id) several times.

Comment: But sometimes it's better to make several queries with smaller responses then having one big response - because of the network load, and because big queries load the database.